# Run Command on Multiple of Files or Single File

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, command

I needed to convert several pnm image files to jpeg with pnmtojpeg. So I used this script, which I named 'pnm2jpg':

```
for f in *.pnm;
  do pnmtojpeg -quality=85 "$f" > "${f%.pnm}.jpg";
done
```

This works very nicely. However, I would like to adapt it further so that it can be used for a single file as well.

In other words, if no files are specified in the command line, then process all the files.

```
$ pnm2jpg thisfile.pnm  # Process only this file.

$ pnm2jpg  # Process all pnm files in the current directory.
```

Your insight is greatly appreciated- Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    for f in *.pnm; do
        pnmtojpeg -quality=85 "$f" > "${f%.pnm}.jpg"
    done
else
    pnmtojpeg -quality=85 "$1" > "${1%.pnm}.jpg"
fi
```

If you execute `pnm2jpg` without an argument the `if` block is processed.

if you execute `pnm2jpg thisfile.pnm` the `else` block is processed.

Comment: Thanks user3439894, this looks excellent. Could you please explain what the double brackets and the '-z' are for?

Comment: It can be written with either one or two square braces and I prefer using two as this is the default in the editor (Sublime) I use.  Have a look at [BashFAQ/031](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) and [Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).  If you then need further explanation let me know.